# How to put ActionBarActivity in to fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

i want to do something like at the pictures.
It will be easy if a can put ActionBarActivity in fragment.
I try to create ActionBarActivity with layout file witch consist ViewPager (it will display 2 tabs and fragments in it)  and FrameLayout which will display other activities. But it does not work because i can not hide ViewPager. I will be glad to get any ideas how to solve this.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use TabPageIndicator from Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator (https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) to display tabs above your ViewPager.

When you want to display another fragment (like in image 2), simply hide the TabPageIndicator and the ViewPager, and then add your Fragment to your FrameLayout and show it.